# Say as cannot find interpret-as in config

Tags: xml, vxml

I have a problem with the sayas vxml, he connot  find interpret as, knowing that it is normally default in vxml 
can someone help me

```
<prompt>
<say-as interpret-as="number">123</say-as>
</prompt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSML specification does not provide a list of values for the "interpret-as" attribute; it is instead left up to the implementation.  You may need to consult the documentation for your SSML processor.

On the other hand, the VoiceXML 2.0 specification *does* mandate a few builtin types for grammars and the "say-as" element.  Note that since "say-as" is actually SSML, you normally **must** prefix the builtin types with the "vxml:" namespace.  You'll need to consult the documentation for your VoiceXML browser to determine whether this is the case.  The VoiceXML builtins are:

- vxml:boolean
- vxml:date
- vxml:digits
- vxml:currency
- vxml:number  *<-- This is the droid you are looking for.*
- vxml:phone
- vxml:time

More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dmlABuiltins

Comment: thank you for your answer, i found what was wrong in my code, it's was my configuration i didn't declare my say as.